# How to create a key,value pair if it doesn't exist in get function?

Tags: c#

I have a get api like the below:

```
bool GetValue<T>(string key, out T value);
```

if the value exists, it is returned in `value` and the function returns true. Otherwise, `value` is set to `default(T)` and the function returns false.

Similarly, I have the set api:

```
bool SetValue<T>(string key, T value);
```

Therefore, currently I am using this like:

```
var exists = GetValue<Details>(@"ProductDetails", out var result);
if (!exists)
{
    _details = new Details();
    SetValue(@"ProductDetails", _details);
}
else
{
    _details = result;
}
```

I want to create a function that does this in a single line. That is, if the value doesn't already exist it creates a new value with the given arguments and stores that.

How can I do this ?

Comment: The only way would be to create static method :  Details.GetDetails(@"ProductDetails", _details).  Then you can use : _details = exists ? _details : Details.GetDetails(@"ProductDetails", _details);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private T GetOrCreate<T>(string tableName)
    where T : new()
{
    T result;

    var exists = GetValue<T>(tableName, out result);
    if (!exists)
    {
        result = new T();
        SetValue(tableName, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Should do it, using a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to make sure a default constructor exists for `T`.

Comment: I like your answer. Is there a way I could provide variable argument list that I could pass to the constructor of T ?

Comment: @Monku You could pass in a `Func<T>` that builds a new instance in case it cannot be retrieved in this case (and remove the generic constraint) but it would only work if you know from the calling code the arguments to build the new instance.

Comment: According to the documentation as well as my IDE, you need to add parantheses to your `new` contraint. I would edit myself, but I can't make changes of less than 6 characters. Neat feature, by the way, I didn't know of it until now.

Comment: @KristofferLerbækPedersen Your doc is correct, thanks